# Long String in Flutter DropdownMenuItem causing overlapping

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I've got a `DropdownButton` in my Flutter app that contains some fairly long strings and i'm having an issue with some text overlapping in the `DropdownMenuItems`. There is a link to the image and in there you can see the text from one option is overlapping with the next option. I tried to wrap the text in an expanded but that isn't doing the trick.

Is there a way to create some equal separation between the `DropdownMenuItems`? I've tried to play around with softwrap and overflow but these are simply cutting the Strings short which is not ideal as the user needs to be able to fully read each item from the `DropDown`.

Ideally an equal gap between each item and no overlap is the outcome i'm looking for. Surely there is a solution to having long strings in a dropdown

[image]

```
DropdownMenuItem(
    value: value,
    child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[Expanded(child: Text(value))],
    ))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
DropdownButton(
isExpanded: true, //just add this property as true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Expanded( // wrap the DropdownButton with Expanded widget
  child: DropdownButton(
    isExpanded: true, // also set the isExpanded property to true
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: Also, this is virtually identical to Joel’s answer from a year ago. When answering old questions, please be sure to review the existing answers.